# Save mat-expansion-panel state after switching page

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Example:

1. **example-page**: I open various expansion panels on this page.
2. I then switch to a different page.
3. I then switch back to the "example-page" and the panels I had
   previously opened are still open.

Can anyone give a general idea of how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain some form of state in between page navigations:  I guess you could work with saving data in a cookie/session, use a service to maintain state data or use some kind of store/redux principle (ngrx, and others)

Answer (score 1):

I think a good option would be instoring a Store to manage State, the popular library for Angular is Ngrx Store, you can find the documentation here https://github.com/ngrx/store

Answer (score 0):

It pretty straightforward and uses a profile service and a getter and setter. I am not sure how efficient it is, but it does work.

1) First the Service, Create a service, if you are using the CLI all the better use the defaults. Add a property to the service of type number;

```
public panelCurrentlyExpanded: number;
```

2) In your component inject your service into the constructor (google it if that means nothing), then create a getter and setter with the same property name (it doesn't need to be the same BTW)

```
  get panelCurrentlyExpanded(): number {
    if (this.profileSvc.panelCurrentlyExpanded !== undefined ) {
      return this.profileSvc.panelCurrentlyExpanded;
    }
  }
  set panelCurrentlyExpanded(value: number) {
    this.profileSvc.panelCurrentlyExpanded = value;
  }
```

3) Next create a couple of methods to set and check the "expanded" property.

```
  isExpanded(idx: number) {
    if (this.panelCurrentlyExpanded !== undefined) {
      if (idx === this.panelCurrentlyExpanded) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  setExpanded(idx: number): void {
    this.panelCurrentlyExpanded = idx;
  }
```

4) Open your HTML and find your Expansion Panel. My panels are being created dynamically so I have a ngFor statement. This thing here is to expose the index of the panel.

```
  mat-expansion-panel (opened)="setExpanded(i)"
  [expanded]="isExpanded(i)" *ngFor="let cat of categories let i = index;"
```

The opened click sends the index to the service for storage. The expanded property checks the value of its index with the stored one and if matches opens it.

I'am sure there is a better method thou.

I hope it helps you out.